# Evaluate constant expression during compile time

Tags: c, constant-expression

I am trying to write a preprocessor macro `MYPRINTF(x, ...)` that should work as `printf` but with an additional length specifier `w`. The definition of `w` is supposed to be operating system dependent, but on Linux it is equivalent to `l`.

The code works fine, but I'm having problems with evaluating expressions during compile time when `x` is a constant expression. As an example, if I write

```c
long int x = 13;
MYPRINTF("%wd\n", x);
```

on a Linux system, I would like the compiler to convert it during compile time to

```c
long int x = 13;
printf("%ld\n", x);
```

Looking at the assembly code, I can say that this is not what is happening.

Here is the code that I'm running

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SET_CHAR(ptr, cr)                       \
    do                                          \
    {                                           \
        *(ptr) = (cr);                          \
        (ptr)++;                                \
    } while (0)

#define SET_WORD_FMT(x)                         \
    do                                          \
    {                                           \
        SET_CHAR(x, 'l');                       \
    } while (0)

#define IS_FORMAT(c) ((c) == 'c' || (c) == 's' || (c) == 'd' || (c) == 'i' || (c) == 'o' || (c) == 'x' || (c) == 'X' || (c) == 'u' || (c) == 'f' || (c) == 'F' || (c) == 'e' || (c) == 'E' || (c) == 'a' || (c) == 'A' || (c) == 'g' || (c) == 'G' || (c) == 'n' || (c) == 'p')

#define MYPRINTF(x, ...)                        \
    do                                          \
    {                                           \
        char _str[512];                         \
        char * _strptr = _str;                  \
        const char * _xptr = (x);               \
        while (*_xptr != '\0')                  \
        {                                       \
            if (*_xptr != '%')                  \
            {                                   \
                SET_CHAR(_strptr, *_xptr);      \
                _xptr++;                        \
                continue;                       \
            }                                   \
                                                \
            SET_CHAR(_strptr, '%');             \
            _xptr++;                            \
                                                \
            if (*_xptr == '%')                  \
            {                                   \
                SET_CHAR(_strptr, '%');         \
                _xptr++;                        \
                continue;                       \
            }                                   \
            else while (!IS_FORMAT(*_xptr))     \
            {                                   \
                SET_CHAR(_strptr, *_xptr);      \
                _xptr++;                        \
            }                                   \
                                                \
            if (_strptr[-1] == 'w')             \
            {                                   \
                _strptr--;                      \
                SET_WORD_FMT(_strptr);          \
            }                                   \
                                                \
            SET_CHAR(_strptr, *_xptr);          \
            _xptr++;                            \
        }                                       \
        *_strptr = '\0';                        \
        printf(_str, __VA_ARGS__);              \
    } while (0)

int
main()
{
    long int slx = 18273817628731872;
    int x = 13;
    int lx = 7128172;
    long long int llx = 1928398172938791872;

    MYPRINTF("hello %wd, %d, %ld, %% and %lld\n", slx, x, lx, llx);
}
```

which is compiled using GCC 12.1.0 with flags `-O3 -march=native`.

Is it possible to evaluate this during compile time? If so, how?

Comment: The usual way is `printf("%" w "d\n", x);` and have `#define w "l" /* or whatever */`. BTW: I suggest you use something other than `w` :-) ... see [`<inttypes.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html)

Comment: What @pmg is suggesting is much the same as the way the "standard" library implements its format specifiers for the fixed-width integer types.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45922817/10871073 for example.

Comment: @pmg Thanks for your answer. I'm already aware of this, and this would be my preferred solution. However, as this is intended to replace a function within a library, I cannot do this.

Comment: An array variable is not a constant expression. A compiler is not obligated to compute it at compile time. `clang` sometimes can do this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/oMo6qzn17) but not when your calculations are as complex as in your macro. `gcc` doesn't seem to do it at all.

Comment: If you really need this to be done at compile time, your best bet is probably a source level transformation (replace `...%w...` with `... %" WIDE "...` in a dedicated build step). I don't think it makes a lot of sense though. Just do it at run time. Code that doesn't want to follow best practices should suffer, how else can we teach it to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to evaluate this during compile time?

No, it is not possible.

For example, writing of a constant-expression strlen for strings up to 62 is *very* memory consuming and your compiler can easily hit gigabytes of memory (mostly, because the generated preprocessor code takes so much). Writing a constant-expression string parsing function for every possible case is just not feasible and not compilable in practice.

If you want such functionality, move to a different programming language or run a preprocessor through your code. For example, preprocess your code with M4 preprocessor.

```
// run with m4 -P
m4_define(`MYPRINTF', `printf(m4_patsubst(`$1', `%wd', `%ld'), m4_shift($@))')
MYPRINTF("%wd", a)   // expands to printf("%ld", a)
```

> that should work as printf but with an additional length specifier w

With glibc you can redefine `%d` conversion and add `w` flag. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Registering-New-Conversions.html

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to define a separate macro with the length specifier in an OS dependent way.  Then you can use that where you want.

```
#ifdef __linux__
#define WIDE "l"
#else
#define WIDE "L"
#endif

...

printf("%" WIDE "d\n", x);
```

Note that this takes advantage of automatic combination of consecutive string literals.

Comment: Thanks. However, this is not accepted in my situation. I'm only looking for a way to convert a constant string during compile time.

Comment: @aahlback Not possible. C++ can do it, I think.

Comment: @user253751 Do you have a source for this? GCC can evaluate other things during compile time, why can't it do it for this case?

Comment: @aahlback  You're looking at the problem the wrong way.  If all you want is a custom width specifier, the above is the way to do it.

Comment: @aahlback The preprocessor doesn't perform substitutions inside of string literals. So you can't use the preprocessor to modify string literals. You need to write your own preprocessor to do that.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, this would be my preferred solution. However, the macro I'm writing is supposed to be a replacement for a function in a library where I'm not able to write it this way for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm creating another string and then I'm copying the content from the string literal; I'm not modifying the string literal.

Comment: @aahlback You seem to be trying to use the C++ `constexpr` feature. There is no such feature in C.

Comment: Re "*where I'm not able to write it this way for backwards compatibility reasons*", Then you will need to do it at run time (like in the Question).